# Ruby- Why can't I iterate over this data that I get back from Mongomapper map_reduce?

Tags: ruby

This is probably simple, but I have spent way too much time trying to figure it out, and am sure someone here will know, so here goes. Please be patient.

Bottom line is that I've got some data that I can't figure out how to loop over.

```
#Get the data from mongomapper map_reduce
@urls = DistinctUrls.build.find()

puts @urls.count
3
puts @urls.to_json
[{"_id":"http://msn.com","value":3.0},{"_id":"http://yahoo.com","value":12.0},{"_id":"http://google.com","value":2.0}]

@urls.each do |entry|
   puts "Here I am"  # Never gets printed, not sure why.
   puts "url" +  entry['_id'] 
end
```

What I don't understand is that if I have a count of 3, why it won't enter the loop?

I'm not sure if the mongomapper or map_reduce details matter. I'm putting them here just in case. If it makes sense, I can add the details of the map/reduce if needed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the class of `@urls`? Maybe `each` is not what you expect.

Comment: Aha, I think you are on to it. The class of @urls is Mongo::Cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you wrote `@urls` then `@url`. I think only one of them is correct.

*Update:* As the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html#each-instance_method) says you can iterate over the cursor with `each` but after the full iteration it will be closed. Maybe this is your case that you've already iterated over it once. Probably the `to_json` did it.

You can check whether the cursor is closed or not with the following statement:

```
@urls.closed?
```

Check this before the iterating part.

Comment: If the `-w` flag was used, the program would warn if you use an instance variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: All of them are defined here. But yes, `-w` could help a lot.

Comment: @KARASZI, you solved it. If I move the `@urls.each` before the `.to_json`, it works like a charm. Thanks so much for your help.